# Lost data with multiple NSManagedObjectContexts on iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I'm in the progress of updating an existing app for iOS 7 and I've been having some issues with Core Data saving objects. It's a fairly straightforward master-detail style data entry app that uses Core Data for the storage.

When adding a new record I use a second (temporary) managed object context to prevent the record appearing in the list before the record is saved. When a record is added and saved it is visible in the list as expected. However if I exit the app (it doesn't run in the background) and then restart it the record is no longer present. The record is present in the database (visible using the SQLite Manager Firefox plugin anyway), but it just doesn't show in the app.

I've managed to reproduce this using the code that Xcode produces when creating a new project. I've created a new master-detail application and ticked the Use Core Data box to get the example code, then made the following changes:

Add the following to MasterViewController.m

```
-(void)save:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    if (context != [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext])
    {
        NSNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [dnc addObserver:self selector:@selector(addControllerContextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:context];
    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        abort();
    }

    if (context != [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext])
    {
        NSNotificationCenter *dnc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [dnc removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:context];
    }
}

- (void)addControllerContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)saveNotification
{
    [[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
}
```

Replace the supplied `insertNewObject` in insertNewObject with the following to create a new temporary context for adding

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.
    [self save:context];
}
```

I also set the app to not run in the background.

If I run this against iOS 6 it behaves as expected i.e. I tap Add and a new record appears, then exit and restart the app and the record is still present.

However if I run the same code against iOS 7 it doesn't work correctly. Tapping Add causes the new record to appear, but if I exit and them restart the app the record is not shown. As mentioned above it is present in the database however.

Interestingly, I've discovered that it might be in some way related to the change in the journaling mode of the SQLite database. If I add the following options in the call to `addPersistentStoreWithType` I get the expected behaviour running on iOS 7

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };
```

So, to the questions (and thanks for reading this far!)

- Has anyone else seen this behaviour (or is anyone able to reproduce it based on the description above)?
- Is there something wrong with the way I am using a temporary context that I was just lucky with prior to iOS 7, or does this look like an issue with the Core Data framework on iOS 7?

Cheers

Neil

Edit 1:

In answer to Wain's question about saving the main MOC, I was under the impression that this isn't actually necessary because the data is already saved, the merge just updates the already saved changes from the temporary context in to the main context. That said the test code does contain the following methods and `saveContext` is called on shutdown, however `[managedObjectContext hasChanges]` returns false so nothing actually gets done at this point

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

-(void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges])
        {
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `includesPendingChanges` on your fetch request?

Comment: @Wain - I guess that would be a possibility (I'm not sure why I didn't, possibly I wasn't aware of that parameter when I wrote the original code) but really I'd like to understand why my app works as expected on <iOS 7 but is broken on 7.

Comment: How (or rather, when) are you saving the persistent context?

Comment: @Wain - I've added to the original post

Comment: I think it should work the way you have it (check the files are updated on disk after the addition). Setting `journal_mode` to `DELETE` is basically resetting to the pre iOS 7 value. Consider raising a radar with your sampled project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed when you save your main context after merging changes:

```
- (void)addControllerContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)saveNotification
{
    [[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];

    [self save:[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext]];
}
```

**UPDATE:** this error was caused by using cache in `NSFetchedResultsController`. So, the data isn't lost, it's just not displayed by your `NSFetchedResultsController`. Further investigation is needed to find out why cache isn't updated when its MOC merges changes, but isn't saved.

Comment: Interesting, that does seem to fix the problem. I'd be very interested to see if you work out why it's happening, as I don't think it should be necessary and it's odd that the behaviour changes when using a different journalling type.

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz. I've submitted a bug report to Apple: 15161551